# C# loading data from a file and sorting into arrays

Tags: c#, c++, visual-studio

So I need to read from a file  and display it all in a suitable format. So far I can read all the data in and it does show on the form however from the `HRData` it only reads in 1 full line and displays that on the form I need it to display every line from that specific part of the file. I've put down a snippet of my code where Iread from the file and display the `HRData` from that file, but I need every line to be in the table and not the repeat of the same line. Any Help would be appreciated. Sorry for the layout of my code I'm still trying the get used to stack over flow so apologies.

```
DateTime date = new DateTime(2014, 09, 08, 16, 0, 0);

string[] Data1 = Regex.Split(filetext, "HRData]");
Data1[1] = Data1[1].Trim();
string[] HRData = Regex.Split(Data1[1], "\r\n|\r\n");

dataGridView1.ColumnCount = 7;
dataGridView1.ColumnHeadersVisible = true;

DataGridViewCellStyle columnHeaderStyle = new DataGridViewCellStyle();

columnHeaderStyle.BackColor = Color.Beige;
columnHeaderStyle.Font = new Font("Verdana", 10, FontStyle.Bold);
dataGridView1.ColumnHeadersDefaultCellStyle = columnHeaderStyle;

dataGridView1.Columns[0].Name = "Time";
dataGridView1.Columns[1].Name = "Heart Rate (bpm)";
dataGridView1.Columns[2].Name = "Speed";
dataGridView1.Columns[3].Name = "Cadence (rpm)";
dataGridView1.Columns[4].Name = "Altitude (m/ft)";
dataGridView1.Columns[5].Name = "Power (watts)";
dataGridView1.Columns[6].Name = "Power Balance";



if (Versionval == 106)
{
    String FindVersionMode = "VersionMode";
    int indexofVersionMode = filetext.IndexOf(FindVersionMode);
    VersionModeTypeA = filetext.Substring(indexofVersionMode + 5, 1);
    VersionModeTypeB = filetext.Substring(indexofVersionMode + 6, 1);
    VersionModeTypeC = filetext.Substring(indexofVersionMode + 7, 1);
    VersionModeTypeD = filetext.Substring(indexofVersionMode + 8, 1);
    VersionModeTypeE = filetext.Substring(indexofVersionMode + 9, 1);
    VersionModeTypeF = filetext.Substring(indexofVersionMode + 10, 1);
    VersionModeTypeG = filetext.Substring(indexofVersionMode + 11, 1);
    VersionModeTypeH = filetext.Substring(indexofVersionMode + 12, 1);

    //SpeedType = Int32.Parse(VModeTypeA);
    //CadenceType = Int32.Parse(VModeTypeA);
    //AltType = Int32.Parse(VModeTypeA);
    //PowerType = Int32.Parse(VModeTypeA);
    //PowerLRBType = Int32.Parse(VModeTypeA);
    //PowerPIType = Int32.Parse(VModeTypeA);
    // HRCCType = Int32.Parse(VModeTypeA);
    // EuroUsType = int.Parse(VModeTypeA);

    dataGridView1.Columns[3].Name = "Cadence (rpm)";
    dataGridView1.Columns[4].Name = "Altitude (m/ft)";
    dataGridView1.Columns[5].Name = "Power (watts)";
    dataGridView1.Columns[6].Name = "Power Balance";

}

    for (int i = 0; i < HRData.Length; i++)
    {

        date = date.AddSeconds(1);
        string[] HRDataColumn = Regex.Split(HRData[1], "\t");
        double speed1 = Int32.Parse(HRDataColumn[1]);
        speed1 = speed1 / 10;
        HRDataColumn[1] = speed1.ToString();
        dataGridView1.Rows.Add(date.ToString("HH:mm:ss"), HRDataColumn[0], HRDataColumn[1], HRDataColumn[2], HRDataColumn[3], HRDataColumn[4], HRDataColumn[5]);

}
```

> [HRData] 
>   91    154 70  309 83  6451 91 154 70  309 83  6451
>   92    160 75  309 87  5687 94 173 80  309 87  5687 96 187 87  309 95  4662
>   100   190 93  309 123 4407 101    192 97  309 141 4915
>   103   191 98  309 145 5429 106    190 99  309 157 4662

So this is a snippet of the `HRData` part of the file theirs a lot more data then that, but I cant paste all of it and so far my code only reads in the first line successfully in each column of the table. Keeps repeating the same line.
so the first line that keeps repeating is: `91  154 70  309 83  6451`

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are always using the same string array `HRDataColumn`

```
string[] HRDataColumn = Regex.Split(HRData[1], "\t");
```

Try to change this line to

```
string[] HRDataColumn = Regex.Split(HRData[i], "\t");
```

Comment: omg thankyou so much it worked! i feel so stupid that it was only 1 thing i had to change. Thankyouuu